# How would I mock a method of a real object and access the method arguments?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I'm using `Mockito` to write some tests in my Java code. In my test, I have a real object, but I want to mock what happens in one of the methods and be able to access the method arguments.

If I do this:

```
MyObj spyObj = spy(new MyObj());
doReturn(false).when(spyObj).myMethod(anyObject(), anyObject(), anyList(), anyLong());
```

I can't access the arguments and do any sort of logic with them.

However, if I use `Mockito.when()` like so:

```
when(spyObj.myMethod(anyObject(), anyObject(), anyList(), anyLong())).thenAnswer(invocation -> {
  if (invocation.getArguments()[0] == 1) {
      // do stuff
      return true;
  }
  return false;
});
```

the real method runs instead of the mocked method. How would I be able to have my test run my mocked method and be able to access the arguments inside the mocked method? Thanks!

Comment: Not using Mocikto extensively but perhaps this can help: http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html#13 and some stuff here: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Mockito/article.html#mockito_spy

Comment: Use doAnswer().when(), just like you use doReturn().when(). See http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html#12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax you want is

```
doAnswer(invocation -> { whatever }).when(spyObj).myMethod( whatever );
```

This lets you stub a method of a spy, without actually invoking it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you don't need a mock. Extend and override.

For example if you have a class like this:

```
class Person {
    String login(String username, String password) {
        return LoginManager.login(username, password);
    }
}
```

Notice the static call `LoginManager.login` that cannot be easily injected.
You can create an anonymous sub-class of `Person` and override the `login` method and do in it whatever you need:

```
@Test
public void test_something() {
    Person person = new Person() {
        @Override
        String login(String username, String password) {
            return "whatever";
        }
    };
}
```

This way you have full control over the overridden method,
and the rest of the behavior of the class is unchanged.

Comment: This was my thought as well. The problem is with immutable and final classes that cannot be extended